# Unit Root Test - Order of Integration (Johansen)

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Let's assume we have 2 variables and test each of them for a unit root with the ADF test. When plotting the data, we can see that it has some up/down movements but is overall clearly trending upwards.

***At level***, variable A is stationary with "no constant", "constant" and "constant+trend" (p<0.05). Variable B is only stationary with "constant+trend" (p<0.05).

***At first differences***, both variables are stationary at "no constant", "constant" and "constant+trend" (p<0.05).

Is it o.k. to conclude that Variable A and B are both integrated of the same order *I(1)*, or do we have to assume that Variable B is *I(0)* with respect to a trend and Variable B is I(1)?

I want to conduct a *Johansen Cointegration test* and after reading the literature and several posts, I'm still not sure if it's okay test for correlation with the data *at level* (and a trend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable A seems to be stationary as whatever the specification ("no constant", "constant", "constant+trend") of the test regression you still reject the unit root hypothesis. Therefore you *cannot* conclude that A~I(1). Since at least one of the two variable is stationary, you *cannot* proceed to cointegration analysis (recall that it requires both variables to be integrated to begin with).

Note on proceeding to testing stationarity of A at first differences: you should not do that as A is already stationary in levels. If A is stationary in levels, testing for stationarity in first differences is redundant when your question is whether A should be included in cointegration analysis.

Comment: So there's no way to test the order of cointegration of variable A and B?

Comment: Lütkepohl and Krätzig, Applied Time Series Econometrics, 2004:

"Occasionally it is convenient to consider systems with both I(1) and I(0) variables. Thereby the concept of cointegration is extended by calling any linear combination that is I(0) a cointegration relation, although this terminology is not in the spirit of the original definition because it can happen that a linear combination of I(0)variables is called a cointegration relation."

Comment: When you only have two variables one of which is stationary and one of which is integrated, there is no way of obtaining a stationary linear combination of the two --> No cointegration. If both of the variables are stationary, again you cannot talk about cointegration. Only in systems of more than two variables is your above quote meaningful.

Comment: So it's no possibility to use the level of the I(0) variable and the
first difference of the I(1) variable?

Comment: If you do that, you are working with two I(0) objects. You can use them for a variety of things but not for cointegration analysis. If the variables are not *integrated*, they cannot be *co-integrated* (look at the construction of these words).

Comment: I think this last sentence made it clear.